# how to display data from database using $.post

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

hey iam trying to take data from data base using $.post. Here iam taking db data as json ecoded. But i couldn't display or alert the data. If possible how can i display the json array? how can i check the database values in json format? pls help me. iam using codeigniter

```
function profile_view(id3)
{
      $.post("<? echo base_url();?>Attendance/Prev_leave_record", {id:id3},function(data){
                  //do something
    });
 }
```

**controller**

```
   function Prev_leave_record()
{
    $teacher_id=$this->input->post('id');
    $teacher_details=$this->AM->prev_record($teacher_id);       
    $out=array(
    'teacher_details'=>$teacher_details);
   // echo '{"teacher_details":'.json_encode($teacher_details).'}';
     echo json_encode($out);

}
```

**model**

```
   function prev_record($teacher_id)
{
   $this->db->select('leave_from_date,leave_to_date');
    $this->db->from('leave_data');
    $this->db->where('applied_user_id',$teacher_id);
    $teacher_details=$this->db->get();
    return $teacher_details;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Model:**
Your model made a query but didn't return the result of the query. 
See [Returning Query Results](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html).

```
function prev_record($teacher_id)
{
   //This is opinion, but it will be much more efficient 
   //not using Query Builder for such a simple query
   $sql = "SELECT leave_from_date, leave_to_date FROM leave_data WHERE applied_user_id = ?";
   $query = $this->db->query($sql, [$teacher_id]);

   //always check that the query produced results
   //the next statement returns one row as an array or
   //returns NULL if the query produced no results
   return $query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->row_array(): NULL;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
function Prev_leave_record()
{
   $teacher_id = $this->input->post('id');
   $teacher_details = $this->AM->prev_record($teacher_id);
   if(isset($teacher_details))
   {
      $out['results'] = "Success";
      $out['teacher_details'] = $teacher_details;
   }
   else
   {
     $out['results'] = "Failed"; 
   }    
   echo json_encode($out);
}
```

**javascript:**

```
function profile_view(id3)
{
   $.post("<? echo base_url();?>attendance/prev_leave_record", {id:id3}, 
       function(data)
       {
         console.log(data); //so you can see the structure returned
         if(data.results === "Success){
            alert("Cool, it worked: " + data.teacher_details);
         } else {
            alert("Opps, we didn't get anything.");
         }
       }
   );
}
```

Comment: how to get each column value? like  data.teacher_details['leave_from_date']?

Comment: data.teacher_details is a javascript object so you can use either `data.teacher_details['leave_from_date']` or `data.teacher_details.leave_from_date`

Comment: Thanks, i could alert the data after  parsing of json .  Now i want to show those data in a html table in a popup. For that i used $.each function. After that i couldn't display those alerted data why?                                `$.each(result, function(index, obj){
                $('#we').append('<tr><td>' + obj.teacher_details['leave_from_date']+'-'+ obj.teacher_details['leave_to_date'] + '</td><td>');

            });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function profile_view(id3)
{
      $.post("<? echo base_url();?>Attendance/Prev_leave_record", {id:id3},function(data){
                  console.log(data); // or alert(data);
    });
 }
```

Then check the console from Inspect element from browser (F12 or ctrl+shift+i)

Comment: <p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: type is unsupported, encoded as null</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/Attendance.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 68</p>

</div>{"teacher_details":{"conn_id":null,"result_id":null,"result_array":[],"result_object":[],"custom_result_object":[],"current_row":0,"num_rows":1,"row_data":null}}

Comment: this is the problem with json_encode() function. please check that, check the line no mentioned in the error message and check.